# How to know when to use a direct and indirect object pronoun

Tags: grammar, french, pronouns, grammatical-object

Il faut les rendre actifs - we have to make them active

Nous devons leur donner le choix - We have to give them the choice

Please can someone explain why the second sentence takes an indirect object pronoun?

Both the sentences' structure seem exactly the same yet have different pronouns...

Comment: French usage questions should be asked at [french.se].

Comment: @curiousdannii The question might need rephrasing but I think it belongs here.  We suggested they asked here because  after exchanging a few comments it seemed that their issue is more about understanding what direct and indirect objects are, whatever the language. Why does English have a direct object pronoun where French has an indirect one, etc.  I thought a more general approach was needed than just telling them they have to learn what verbs requires direct or indirect object.

Comment: @Laure Ah. Well, I don't think "direct" and "indirect" objects are really used very much by linguists. They're just labels of convention with no real substance, and it's often a mistake to try to port them between languages. "Why does English have a direct object pronoun where French has an indirect one" isn't a question with a meaningful answer IMO. (At least I've never heard DO/IO explained in a way that makes much linguistic sense.)

Comment: @curiousdannii Don't you think expanding on "They're just labels of convention with no real substance" could be interesting? There's a "grammatical-object"  tag though and I've seen questions about grammatical relations.

Answer (score 2):

In many languages, including French and English, verbs generally take zero to three nouns as "arguments".

- Zero: "it's raining"
- One: "I'm walking"
- Two: "I'm eating a cake"
- Three: "I'm giving you a cake" / "I'm giving a cake to you"

Traditionally, the first argument is called the "subject", the second is the "direct object", and the third is the "indirect object".

In English, when a verb takes three arguments, there are two standard ways to put the pieces together:

- Subj Verb Indirect Direct
- Subj Verb Direct to Indirect

But this doesn't change the roles of the nouns: if "I'm sending you a letter", or "I'm sending a letter to you", *I* am the subject, *a letter* is the direct object, and *you* are the indirect object.

That's why you use *leur* in your second sentence: it's the third argument to the verb. The first is *nous* (subject), the second is *le choix* (direct object), the third is *leur* (indirect object). Why do they go in this order? Historical reasons, really: that's just the way French and English evolved, and other languages can and do do it differently.

In the first sentence, on the other hand, the verb only takes two *nouns* as arguments. The first isn't stated (subject), the second is *les* (direct object). There's a third argument, but it isn't a noun, and only nouns fill in these three slots; other types of arguments, even if they're mandatory, don't fit into this same structure. (See also prepositional phrase arguments. These can also be mandatory: you can't just say *"I put the book", you have to put the book *on* something, or *in* something, or *under* something, etc. But they don't fit into the subject-direct object-indirect object system.)

Comment: Your last example, *put the book* is nice; The same was that *put the book away* has *away* as a prepositional object, that is adverbial to the clause (isn`t it),  *put away the book* would have an adverb; and I feel that *devons leur* works very similarly.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, you can see the direct object (accusative case in some languages) and the indirect object (dative case in some languages) in English in your examples:

> ***Who*** do I make active?
>
> To make ***someone*** active.
>
> ***Who*** do I give the choice ***to***?
>
> To give the choice ***to someone***.

Now English has a specificity that makes you can transform this into:

> To give ***someone*** the choice.

I'm not good enough in English to talk about this, but it seems it only works when there is direct complement too (here *the choice*), so I think your question is more "why can we use *them* in English instead of *to them* in some cases?".

When there is only one complement, which is direct:

> J'aime ***mes parents*** => Je ***les*** aime
>
> I love ***my parents*** => I love ***them***

And when it's indirect:

> Je parle ***à mes parents*** => Je ***leur*** parle
>
> I talk ***to my parents*** => I talk ***to them***

And with two complements, a direct one and an indirect one:

> Je donne *des pommes* **à mes parents**
>
> I give *apples* **to my parents** OR I give **my parents** *apples*
>
> Je **leur** donne *des pommes*
>
> I give *apples* **to them** OR I give **them** *apples*
>
> Je *les* **leur** donne
>
> I give *them* **to them**

Can you say "I give them them", with the first *them* being *the parents*?

Comment: It's misleading to call anything in English the dative. English does not have that case.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I'm gonna change the phrasing.